# Selected LinkedIn profiles not loading completely in Selenium using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have written a code to fetch LinkedIn profile details but sometimes the entire HTML is not loaded for some user profiles.

I have already used the classic wait mechanisms i.e.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

time.sleep(10)

element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '.pv-profile-section__card-item-v2.pv-profile-section.pv-position-entity.ember-view'))
WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(element_present)
```

but none of them seem to work.

A snippet of my code:

```
firstName = urllib.parse.quote(userFirstName)
lastName = urllib.parse.quote(userLastName)
company = urllib.parse.quote(userCompany)

driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?company='+company+'&firstName='+firstName+'&lastName='+lastName+'&origin=FACETED_SEARCH')

results = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.name.actor-name'))
for i in range(1):
    print(i)
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.name.actor-name')[i].click()
    time.sleep(10)
    print(driver.current_url)

    content = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    #print(soup)

    companyList = soup.findAll('section',{'class':'pv-profile-section__card-item-v2 pv-profile-section pv-position-entity ember-view'})
    print("Company list length: "+str(len(companyList)))
```

The code does give company list for many users but it simply fails in some cases. I checked those profiles on my browser and the elements in the code did exist.

Any help/ past experience on this would be appreciated. I know trying to solve this problem will also take efforts so thanks in advance!

P.S.: A part of HTML (the experience part I care about):

```
<ul class="pv-profile-section__section-info section-info pv-profile-section__section-info--has-no-more">
<li class="pv-entity__position-group-pager pv-profile-section__list-item ember-view" id="ember394"> <section class="pv-profile-section__card-item-v2 pv-profile-section pv-position-entity ember-view" id="ember396"> <div class="display-flex justify-space-between full-width">
<a class="full-width ember-view" data-control-name="background_details_company" href="/search/results/index/?keywords=Aditya%20Birla%20Direct" id="ember397"> <div class="pv-entity__company-details">
<div class="pv-entity__logo company-logo">
<img alt="Aditya Birla Direct" class="pv-entity__logo-img pv-entity__logo-img EntityPhoto-square-5 lazy-image ember-view" id="ember399"/>
</div>
<div class="pv-entity__company-summary-info">
<h3 class="t-16 t-black t-bold">
<span class="visually-hidden">Company Name</span>
<span>Aditya Birla Direct</span>
</h3>
<h4 class="t-14 t-black t-normal">
<span class="visually-hidden">Total Duration</span>
<span>2 yrs 6 mos</span>
</h4>
</div>
</div>
</a>
<!-- --> </div>
<ul class="pv-entity__position-group mt2 ember-view" id="ember400"><li class="pv-entity__position-group-role-item sortable-item ember-view" id="ember402"> <div class="ember-view" id="ember403"><div class="pv-entity__role-details">
<span class="pv-entity__timeline-node"></span>
<div class="display-flex justify-space-between full-width">
<div class="pv-entity__role-container">
<div class="pv-entity__role-details-container pv-entity__role-details-container--timeline pv-entity__role-details-container--bottom-margin">
<div class="pv-entity__summary-info-v2 pv-entity__summary-info--background-section pv-entity__summary-info-margin-top">
<h3 class="t-14 t-black t-bold">
<span class="visually-hidden">Title</span>
<span>Product Designer</span>
</h3>
<!-- --> <div class="display-flex">
<h4 class="pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
<span class="visually-hidden">Dates Employed</span>
<span>Jun 2018 – Present</span>
</h4>
<h4 class="t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
<span class="visually-hidden">Employment Duration</span>
<span class="pv-entity__bullet-item-v2">1 yr 5 mos</span>
</h4>
</div>
<h4 class="pv-entity__location t-14 t-black--light t-normal block">
<span class="visually-hidden">Location</span>
<span>Mumbai, Maharashtra, India</span>
</h4>
</div>
<!-- --> </div>
</div>
<!-- --> </div>
</div>
</div>
</li><li class="pv-entity__position-group-role-item sortable-item ember-view" id="ember405"> <div class="ember-view" id="ember406"><div class="pv-entity__role-details">
<span class="pv-entity__timeline-node"></span>
<div class="display-flex justify-space-between full-width">
<div class="pv-entity__role-container">
<div class="pv-entity__role-details-container">
<div class="pv-entity__summary-info-v2 pv-entity__summary-info--background-section pv-entity__summary-info-margin-top">
<h3 class="t-14 t-black t-bold">
<span class="visually-hidden">Title</span>
<span>UI/UX Designer</span>
</h3>
<!-- --> <div class="display-flex">
<h4 class="pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
<span class="visually-hidden">Dates Employed</span>
<span>May 2017 – Present</span>
</h4>
<h4 class="t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
<span class="visually-hidden">Employment Duration</span>
<span class="pv-entity__bullet-item-v2">2 yrs 6 mos</span>
</h4>
</div>
<h4 class="pv-entity__location t-14 t-black--light t-normal block">
<span class="visually-hidden">Location</span>
<span>Mumbai, Maharashtra, India</span>
</h4>
</div>
<!-- --> </div>
</div>
<!-- --> </div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
<!-- --></section>
</li><li class="pv-entity__position-group-pager pv-profile-section__list-item ember-view" id="ember408"> <section class="pv-profile-section__card-item-v2 pv-profile-section pv-position-entity ember-view" id="1192970710"> <div class="display-flex justify-space-between full-width">
<div class="display-flex flex-column full-width">
<a class="full-width ember-view" data-control-name="background_details_company" href="/search/results/index/?keywords=improove%20technology%20pvt%20ltd" id="ember411"> <div class="pv-entity__logo company-logo">
<img alt="improove technology pvt ltd" class="pv-entity__logo-img pv-entity__logo-img EntityPhoto-square-5 lazy-image ghost-company ember-view" id="ember413"/>
</div>
<div class="pv-entity__summary-info pv-entity__summary-info--background-section">
<h3 class="t-16 t-black t-bold">UI/UX Designer</h3>
<p class="visually-hidden">Company Name</p>
<p class="pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal">improove technology pvt ltd</p>
<!-- -->
<div class="display-flex">
<h4 class="pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
<span class="visually-hidden">Dates Employed</span>
<span>May 2015 – May 2017</span>
</h4>
<h4 class="t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
<span class="visually-hidden">Employment Duration</span>
<span class="pv-entity__bullet-item-v2">2 yrs 1 mo</span>
</h4>
</div>
<h4 class="pv-entity__location t-14 t-black--light t-normal block">
<span class="visually-hidden">Location</span>
<span>Delhi</span>
</h4>
</div>
</a>
<!-- --> </div>
<!-- --> </div>
</section>
</li>
```

I basically need the company name, role and dates employed.

Comment: Is the page endlessly loading?

Comment: @pcalkins, yes, seems so.

Comment: Sometimes setting this flag can help (ChromeOptions, java code here): options.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable")  There are also some new settings for "PageLoadStrategy" which isn't a great solution, but it will at least allow your scripts to continue:  https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/#dfn-page-load-strategy

Answer (score 0):

Based on the updated HTML you posted, it's possible that the `section` element is fully loading, but its contents are not fully loaded, which could result in `companyList` being empty as you mentioned.

I would prefer to wait on something more specific than `section`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Wait on ALL sections to load
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//section[contains(@class, 'pv-profile-section')]")))

# Wait on Company Name labels to load
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Company Name')]")))

# Get company list
companyList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//section[contains(@class, 'pv-profile-section')]")

print(len(companyList))
```

This code will wait on all `section` elements to load, and also wait on the `Company Name` to load -- this might avoid the issue where a `section` is loaded, but its contents are not fully loaded yet.

Comment: I did specify the seconds in implicity_wait; sorry I forgot to include it in the question. I will edit the question to include part of the HTML.

Comment: I did see that you specified in your example, but 2 seconds might not be long enough. I'm also not sure which line of code is throwing an error, or what the error message says -- including that information would be helpful as well.

Comment: there is no error in the code. The problem is the 'companyList' is 0 which indicates that the work experience part of the profile was not loaded. I have updated the question with part of the HTML.

Comment: @makeshift-programmer I've updated my answer with a possible solution including a test to see how many companies are located here. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: the code to load all sections works (doesn't throw an error) but the second line which wait for Company Name to load goes into timeout. Even after increasing the limit to 200 seconds.

Comment: @makeshift-programmer interesting, I wonder if it has trailing whitespace or is related to the `visually-hidden` class there. I've updated the XPath for `Company Name` to a generic `*` and used `contains` query instead of `=`. Let's see if this helps at all. You may have better luck removing that wait entirely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200858/discussion-between-makeshift-programmer-and-christine).